# use php to generate image, the background is always in wrong color

Tags: php, image, gd

The function is when users upload a picture, program will generate a new white background squre image, and put user's picture in the center of this image.

But the problem is, I set the background to white, it always shows black.

The code is

```
$capture = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
$rgb = explode(",", $this->background); 
$white = imagecolorallocate($capture, $rgb[0], $rgb[1], $rgb[2]); 
imagefill($capture, 0, 0, $white);
```

and the code that controls the color is
    `protected $background = "255,255,255";`

I've been tried to change `$white = imagecolorallocate($capture, $rgb[0], $rgb[1], $rgb[2]);` to `$white = imagecolorallocate($capture, 255, 255, 255);`. But the background still shows in black.

Thanks for any answer

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? What is the background color? Also, how are you rendering the image?

Comment: @Zach Rattner it still shows in black instead of white. I use imagejpeg to render image

Comment: ```header ('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
$im = @imagecreatetruecolor(120, 20)
      or die('Cannot Initialize new GD image stream');

$rgb = explode(",", "255,255,255");
$white = imagecolorallocate($im, $rgb[0], $rgb[1], $rgb[2]);
imagefill($im, 0, 0, $white);

imagejpeg($im);``` works for me, are you sure you're not overwriting it later?

Comment: @Deebster thanks. I found that I didn't change the $rgb = explode. But still need the imagefilledrectangle() function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the manual `imagecreatetruecolor() returns an image identifier representing a black image of the specified size.`  The first call to imagecolorallocate sets the background for palette based images but a true color image is not.

The way I set the background color on true color images is to just fill it with a solid rectangle.

```
imagefilledrectangle($capture, 0, 0, $width, $height, $white);
```

Comment: the rectangle works, but I also need to change `$rgb = explode(",", $this->background); ` to `$rgb = explode(",", "255,255,255");`

Answer (score 1):

what about [`imagefill($im, x, y, $color)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagefill.php) ?

```
$red = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 0, 0);
imagefill($im, 0, 0, $red);
```

This will fill entire image with red color, and the `x,y` parameters are the starting point of rectangle fill.